# Subprocess not thread safe, alternatives?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm using `python 2.7` and do not have the option of upgrading or back-porting `subprocess32`. I am using it in a threaded environment in which usually it works fine, however sometimes the `subprocess` creation is not returning and so the thread hangs, even `strace` does not work in the instance of a hang, so I get no feedback.

E.G. this line can cause a hang (data returned is small so it is not a pipe issue):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I have subsequently read that subprocess is not thread safe in python 2.7 and that "various issues" were fixed in the newest versions. I am using multiple threads calling subprocess.

I have demonstrated this problem with the following code (as a demonstrable example - not my actual code) which starts numerous threads with a `subprocess` each:

```
import os, time, threading, sys
from subprocess import Popen
i=0
class Process:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        global i
        retcode = -1
        try:
                self.process = Popen(self.args)
                i+=1
                if i == 10:
                    sys.stdout.write("Complete\n")
                while self.process.poll() is None:
                    time.sleep(1.0)
                retcode = self.process.returncode
        except:
            sys.stdout.write("ERROR\n")

        return retcode

def main():
    processes = [Process(["/bin/cat"]) for _ in range(10)]
    # start all processes
    for p in processes:
        t = threading.Thread(target=Process.run, args=(p,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    sys.stdout.write("all threads started\n")
    # wait for Ctrl+C
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)

main()
```

This will often result in 1 or more `subprocess` calls never returning. Does anybody have more information on this or a solution/alternative

I am thinking of using the deprecated `commands.getoutput` instead but do not know if that is thread safe? It certainly seems to work correctly for the code above.

Comment: Reference to subprocess bugs?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Here is one: http://bugs.python.org/issue2320 (There are more and they're pretty easy to find).

Comment: FWIW, I personally tend to use subprocess32 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/) but it sounds like it's not an option in your environment?

Comment: are all your threads just waiting on a subprocess each? I don't think that is necessary, I think using `asyncio` would be more efficient while not needing threads.

Comment: @NPE Yeah this is not currently an option, I meant to say that, I will edit my post.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I am not familiar with asyncio, I will look into it now thanks. The threads do not just wait on subprocess' but that is the bulk of work that they do, with some decision making based on a state machine. Reworking the code to not use threads may not be possible at this stage since a lot of functionality is built on top of it.

Comment: @tadhg-mcdonald-jensen implies python3, the question seems to be about python2.7

Comment: @newtover shoot I thought it was backported, well I will have to post an answer using generators then.

Comment: If you don't have the possibility of using backports, fix whatever is restricting your possibilities *first*.

Answer (score 2):

If the bulk of what your threads is doing is just waiting on subprocesses you can acomplish this much more effectively with coroutines.  With python2 you would inplement this with generators so the necessary changes to the `run` function are:

1. replace `time.sleep(1.0)` with `yield` to pass control to another routine
2. replace `return retcode` with `self.retcode = retcode` or similar since generators can't return a value [before python3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)

Then the `main` function could be something like this:

```
def main():
    processes = [Process(["/bin/cat"]) for _ in range(10)]
    #since p.run() is a generator this doesn't run any of the code yet
    routines = [p.run() for p in processes]
    while routines:
        #iterate in reverse so we can remove routines while iterating without skipping any
        for routine in reversed(routines): 
            try:
                next(routine) #continue the routine to next yield
            except StopIteration:
                #this routine has finished, we no longer need to check it
                routines.remove(routine)
```

This is intended to give you a place to start from, I'd recommend adding `print` statements around the yields or use [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23%20Use%20generator%20to%20generate%20a%20stream%20of%20primes%0Adef%20gen_primes%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20n%20%3D%202%0A%20%20%20%20while%20True%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20range%282,%20n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%25%20x%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20n%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20n%20%2B%3D%201%0A%0Afor%20p%20in%20gen_primes%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28p%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) to better understand the order of execution.

This has the benefit of never having any threads waiting for anything, just one thread doing a section of processing at a time which can be much more efficient then many idling threads.